# sp_getapplock not working in multiple Connection

Tags: sql-server, locking

I wrote below script and run it in two tab of SQL Server management studio:

```
DECLARE @RC INT
Begin TRAN
    Exec @RC =sp_getapplock @Resource='MyLock', @LockMode='Exclusive', @LockOwner='Transaction', @LockTimeout = 15000

    SELECT @@SPID [session_id], @RC [return code], GETDATE()
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:08'            
COMMIT
```

One of the execution wait 8 seconds and another wait 16 seconds. I was expecting it and every things is fine.
But when I open two SQL Sever management studio which connected same instance, and run this script, It is not working and both executing wait 8 seconds!

**I test my scenario in two Management Studios in two PCs that connected to same SQL Server instance.**

Do sp_getapplock not working in multiple Connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detailing the answer added to the question, according to the [sp_getapplock documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql), (emphasis added):

> The lock resource created by sp_getapplock **is created in the current
>   database for the session**. Each lock resource is identified by the
>   combined values of:

- > **The database ID of the database containing the lock resource.**
- > The database principle specified in the @DbPrincipal parameter.
- > The lock name specified in the @Resource parameter.